# Paypal - Withhold Payment until Confirmed

Tags: paypal, e-commerce, payment, commerce

I have set up a Paypal Merchant account.

One of my requirements is to freeze any payments received through Papyal on my website and only go through once I manually accept them.

Can anyone suggest how to do this please?

Answer (score 0):

You could use your Fraud Management Filters within your profile to flag payments until you accept them if they don't fit the criteria you're after.

I'm pretty sure there's an option to simply force the approval for all payments, but I'm not finding it right now.  You could call PayPal and ask them about that.

Another option would be to utilize Authorize and Capture.  This way the payments that come through the site would simply be authorized with no funds actually processed.  Only when you capture the authorization would the funds be processed and moved into your account.

If you don't want to approve it you could either void the authorization or simply let it expire, which it would generally do within 29 days depending on the payer's bank.